# Neo: children won't display or I get all() deprecation notice

Tags: plugin-neo

I have a Neo field set up like so:

```
-Row
--Column
-Body
```

Columns can also contain `body`.

With this:

```
{% set modules = entry.pageBuilder
        .with([
            'moduleBody',
            'moduleRow',
            'moduleColumn',
        ])
        .level(1)
        .all()
%}

{% for module in modules %}
    {% if module.type != 'moduleColumn' %}
        {% include '_partials/page-builder/_' ~ module.type %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% set moduleArray = [] %}

{# Remove duplicate module types from array #}
{% for moduleType in modules %}
    {% if moduleType.type not in moduleArray %}
        {% set moduleArray = moduleArray|merge([moduleType.type]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**_moduleBody.twig**

```
<div class="module-body mb-8">
  {% if module.heading %}<h2>{{ module.heading }}</h2>{% endif %}
  {{ module.body }}
</div>
```

I get `body` blocks output fine if they're not nested in a row/column.

**_moduleRow.twig**

```
<div class="row flex flex-wrap">
    {% set columns = module.children %}
    {% for column in columns %}
    <div class="md:w-1/{{column.width}} ">
    {% for item in column.children %}
        {% include '_partials/page-builder/_' ~ item.type %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

With the above, I get an error:

> Looping through element queries directly has been deprecated. Use the all() function to fetch the query results before looping over them.

If I change `set columns = module.children` to `set columns = module.children.all()` I get the same thing. If I change it to

```
{% set columns = module.children
        .with(['moduleColumn'])
        .level(1)
        .all()
%}
```

there's no error, but no output either (other than the HTML for the row which is outside the code for the column contents).

What do I need to do to get the columns to output?

I guess I'm also going to have a problem with `for item in column.children` because inside `moduleBody` it's calling `module.variable` not `item.variable` but if the outer loop uses module, I can't use it for the inner loop too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else having a similar problem, the solution was this:

```
    {% for module in entry.pageBuilder.all() %}
        {% do module.useMemoized(entry.pageBuilder) %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for module in entry.pageBuilder.all() if module.level == 1 %}
        {% if module.type != 'moduleColumn' %}
            {% include '_partials/page-builder/_' ~ module.type %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

and then inside **_moduleRow.twig**

```
    <div class="row flex flex-wrap">
        {% for module in module.children.all() %}
            {% if module.type == 'moduleColumn' %}
                <div class="md:w-1/{{module.width}} ">
                {% for module in module.children.all() %}
                    {% include '_partials/page-builder/_' ~ module.type %}
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% else %}
                {% include '_partials/page-builder/_' ~ module.type %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```